# the Coverage Condition fails

Tags: haskell

I have a very simple piece of code as follow:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    MultiParamTypeClasses,
    FunctionalDependencies,
    FlexibleInstances,
    FlexibleContexts
#-}

class Graph g n e | g -> n e where
    nodes           :: g -> [n]                             
    edge            :: g -> (n,n) -> Maybe e                

instance Graph g Int e where
    nodes g = []
    edge g (n1,n2) = Nothing
```

I got an error related to the Coverage Condition fails for one of the functional dependencies. Do I need to add -XUndecidableInstances to permit this? or how I can fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: You functional dependency says that your choice of type `g` determines your node and element types `n` and `e`, respectively. Does it make sense, then, to say that all graph types `g` (knowing nothing about `g`) determine the node type to be `Int`?

Comment: @sabauma, thanks!  I never knew what the coverage condition is, but this little example showed me! :-)

Comment: @luqui Heh, I had never heard of the "coverage condition" before. I was only reasoning about the code.

Comment: @sabauma: you should post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your case is not `Int` but `e`. The Coverage Condition is documented in [GHC's manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html) Sect. *7.6.3.2. Relaxed rules for instance contexts* and says:

> The Coverage Condition. For each functional dependency, tvs<sub>left</sub> -> tvs<sub>right</sub>, of the class, every type variable in S(tvs<sub>right</sub>) must appear in S(tvs<sub>left</sub>), where S is the substitution mapping each type variable in the class declaration to the corresponding type in the instance declaration.

What does it mean in practise? In your case, your functional dependency says `g -> n e`, which means that for each instance the types denoted by `n` and `e` are unique for the type denoted by `g`. Now let's say you're defining an instance

```
instance Graph SomeTypeG SomeTypeN SomeTypeE where
    ...
```

The coverage condition says that any type variable appearing in `SomeTypeE` or `SomeTypeN` must appear in `SomeTypeG`. What happens if it's not satisfied? Let's suppose a type variable `a` appears in `SomeTypeE` but not in `SomeTypeG`. Then for fixed `SomeTypeG` we would have an infinite number of possible instances by substituting different types for `a`.

In your case

```
instance Graph g Int e where
    ...
```

`e` is such a type variable, so by the Coverage Condition it must appear in `g`, which is not true. Because it doesn't appear there, your definition would imply that `Graph g Int Int` is an instances, `Graph g Int (Maybe Char)` is another instance, etc., contradicting the functional dependency that requires that there is precisely one.

If you had defined something like

```
instance Graph g Int Char where
```

then it would be OK, as there are no type variables in `Int` and `Char`. Another valid instance could be

```
instance Graph (g2 e) Int e where
```

where `g2` is now of kind `* -> *`. In this case, `e` appears in `g2 e`, which satisfies the Coverage Condition, and indeed, `e` is always uniquely determined from `g2 e`.

Answer (score 1):

Your functional dependency says that your choice of type g determines your node and element types n and e, respectively. Does it make sense, then, to say that all graph types g (knowing nothing about g) determine the node type to be Int?